# ngxDaterangepickerMd Open datepicker from outside in angular

Tags: angular, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I struggle to open `ngxDaterangepickerMd` from outside. I need two single-datepickers, one for the "from date" and one for the "to date". When I click on the **from**-button the **from**-datepicker should open and when I click on the **to**-button the **to**-datepicker should show up. Yet in my case when I click on the **to**-datepicker, the **from**-datepicker opens instead.

This is the code for my **from**-button:

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker-calendar-icon"  ngxDaterangepickerMd  [locale]="{ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }" [(ngModel)]="startDate" [singleDatePicker]="true"
                        [autoApply]="true" [minDate]="minDate" (change)="setStartDate()" />
<button>from</button>
```

This is the code for my **to**-button:

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker-calendar-icon"  ngxDaterangepickerMd  [locale]="{ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }" [(ngModel)]="endDate" [singleDatePicker]="true"
                        [autoApply]="true" [minDate]="minDate" (change)="setStartDate()" />
<button>to</button>
```

I followed this as reference  https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material#open-datepicker-from-outside

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You see they use `ViewChild` to get the current input (datepicker), ViewChild just like `querySelector` return `1` element, the first one. Since you have 2 inputs, you need to use `ViewChildren`. So you can start learning to use those 2 decorators that Angular provides. If you have any stuck, just post here, we can work together. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren